# No HDMI Output, Video Lag, Windows 10

Tags: audio, video, multiple-monitors, hdmi, windows-10

ive been looking for help to solve my issue for a week now ( since my windows 10 upgrade from win 8.1 ) and i do not want to do a clean install unless it is totally the last resource available, so i hope someone has come with the issue and found a way to solve it.

I was running Windows 8.1 with external monitor via HDMI, sound and video worked flawlessly, but when i upgraded my system to windows 10, i noticed my monitor wont reproduce the audio, Windows is showing audio activity, and my device (HDMI) is set as default in sound properties, another thing i noticed is that video (youtube) starts to stutter when HDMI audio is selected, everything is corrected when i switch back to laptop speakers, audio returns and video starts playing fine.

Ive tried so far the following troubleshoot solutions:

-Unistall sound device
-Reinstall sound drivers
-Disable/Enable device from device manager
-Downgrade drivers
-Windows Sound Troubleshooting
-Plug/ unplug monitor

The most strange thing about this issue is that it happends only with a cold boot, when i boot my system see no sound and video stutter, i reboot, and sound is on again, and video plays ok, but if i shutdown, and boot again  it gets all wrong again. I also have a friend with same setup as mine, and everything is working fine, no issues at all.

My machine is a Lenovo Y50 (16GB ram, i7-4710HQ (intel HD4600), and Geforce GTX860m)

Hope someone can help me, im totally frustrated now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got the solution! Disable Hyper V from Windows Features!
It will work like a charm!

EDIT:

Following Mokubai's suggestion, I want to add the post where the [solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/windows-10-hdmi-audio-not-working/293eec79-e0f8-4837-bbd0-341cfc9bd446?auth=1) is provided.

Unfortunatly I can't provide more infos on how Hyper-V interacts with HDMI audio (I'm not skilled enough).

Comment: It would be nice if you could [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/983113/edit) your answer to include information on *why* this answers the question.  How did you find out that this was the problem and solution?  What exactly does disabling it do that fixes the problem?

Comment: Amazing leo !!! works like a charm...

Comment: Glad it helped you!